# Jupyter notebook not showing output on vs code mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I installed the Jupyter Notebook to VS Code, but when I try to run anything it does not show me an output. Does anyone know why? And how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't connected to any Jupyter servers, so the cells are actually waiting to be run. Please see [Visual Studio Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) on how to set up:

> #### Setting up your environment
>
> To work with Python in Jupyter Notebooks, you must activate an Anaconda environment in VS Code, or another Python environment in which you've installed the Jupyter package. To select an environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
>
> Once the appropriate environment is activated, you can create and open a Jupyter Notebook, connect to a remote Jupyter server for running code cells, and export a Jupyter Notebook as a Python file.

Once a cell is ran properly, there should be a green tick under the cell like below: [image: Jupyter cell ran in VSCode]

Answer (score 0):

If you configured a virtual environment, you have to select it again with (Ctrl+Shift+P) after your reboot your machine.